# Select utilizando Join com Distinct

Tags: sql, firebird, join, inner

Tenho duas tabelas:

**tb_movimento**

```
| cod | dt_producao  | qt_prod |
|-----|--------------|---------|
|   1 | '04.08.2016' |      10 |
|   2 | '04.08.2016' |       5 |
|   3 | '09.08.2016' |      12 |
|   4 | '10.08.2016' |       3 |
```

**tb_romaneio**

```
| cod | dt_romaneio  | qt_entregue |
|-----|--------------|-------------|
|   1 | '09.08.2016' |        2356 |
|   2 | '04.08.2016' |         156 |
|   3 | '04.08.2016' |        4563 |
|   4 | '04.08.2016' |        1253 |
```

Preciso fazer a média do qt_prod e qt_entregue pegando entre duas datas, estou fazendo assim:

```
SELECT T1.DT_PRODUCAO, SUM(T1.QT_PROD), SUM(T3.QT_ENTREGUE)
FROM TB_MOVIMENTO T1
INNER JOIN TB_ROMANEIO T3 ON (T3.DT_ROMANEIO = T1.DT_PRODUCAO)
WHERE
(T1.DT_PRODUCAO BETWEEN '04.08.2016' AND '09.08.2016')
GROUP BY
T1.DT_PRODUCAO
```

Mas não está trazendo como eu quero, preciso que me traga assim:

```
| dt_producao  | qt_prod | qt_entregue |
|--------------|---------|-------------|
| '04.08.2016' |      15 |         156 |
| '09.08.2016' |      12 |        2356 |
```

Comment: O que está trazendo para você?

Comment: antes de group by não tem and, e o que tem o Distinct do titulo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inicialmente pensei em responder a esta pergunta usando uma SubQuery, mas vendo que o Firebird dá suporte à [`Common Table Expressions`](http://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-select.html#langrefupd21-select-cte) (MySql... Estou olhando para você)

```
WITH CTE_Movimento AS (
    SELECT dt_producao, SUM(qt_prod) as qt_prod
    FROM tb_movimento 
    GROUP BY dt_producao
), CTE_Romaneio AS (
    SELECT dt_romaneio, SUM(qt_entregue) as qt_entregue
    FROM tb_romaneio 
    GROUP BY dt_romaneio 
)

SELECT dt_producao, qt_prod, qt_entregue 
FROM CTE_Movimento
JOIN CTE_Romaneio ON CTE_Movimento.dt_producao = CTE_Romaneio.dt_romaneio
WHERE dt_producao BETWEEN '04.08.2016' AND '09.08.2016'
```

Comment: Muito obrigado..Fiz com SubQuery tbm deu certo..